# restricting the selection of checkboxes

Tags: javascript

how do i get the user to check only one of these checkboxes  .. is there any way other than disabling the checkboxes on selection??

```
<td width="25%"><input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="Good" />Good</td>
<td width="25%"><input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="Average" />Average</td>
<td width="25%"><input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="Sucks" />Sucks</td>
<td width="25%"><input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="Fascinating" />Fascinating</td>
```

if its a javascript, please make it simple to understand ..

Comment: How come "Sucks" is followed by "Fascinating"........

Comment: Yes, use radio buttons - that's what they're for (http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for a [radio button group](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

```
<td width="25%"><input type="radio" name="choice" value="Good" />Good</td>
<td width="25%"><input type="radio" name="choice" value="Average" />Average</td>
<td width="25%"><input type="radio" name="choice" value="Sucks" />Sucks</td>
<td width="25%"><input type="radio" name="choice" value="Fascinating" />Fascinating</td>
```

Comment: +1, darnit! Beat me by 3 seconds :-P Here's an example for the OP: http://jsfiddle.net/avXs3/

Comment: @Andy I was going to reply that I was faster because I actually have *hands* to type with, but then I looked at your user name. So glad to see you have your body back! :)

Comment: @Pekka: what, this old thing? Yeah, it's not mine I'm just borrowing it ;)

Comment: @Andy Awww. NHS issue replacement body? I *keep* telling people you need private insurance for a body transplant! But it's so hard to get people to buy insurance when everything's still attached.

Comment: @Pekka: yeah, luckily they got it right second time.  First attempt they put it on backwards.

Answer (score 0):

If the user can only select one of them at a time, you should use `<input type="radio">` instead of `checkbox`.

If you must use `checkbox`, try ([example](http://jsbin.com/uyudo4)):

```
var choices = document.getElementsByName('choice');

for (var i = choices.length-1; i >= 0; -- i) {
  choices[i].onclick = function () {
    for (var j = choices.length-1; j >= 0; -- j) {
      if (choices[j] != this)
        choices[j].checked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [radio buttons](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) instead for your requirement. When you select, only one of them will get checked.

[Here is the working demo of that :)](http://jsbin.com/owise)